# KnockoutJS Find ko.observable() length

Tags: javascript, if-statement, mvvm, knockout.js

## EDIT Why won't the computed length save?

Is there a way to data-bind an observable only if it has a precision of say 1, 2 or 3?  Below is my VM:

```
function FFS_ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    .....
    self.SortOrder = ko.observable();
    self.SortOrderLen = ko.computed(function(){
          return self.SortOrder().length; // **Error Here: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**
    });
    self.Description = ko.observable();
    self.records = ko.observableArray([]);
})
```

Here is the View:

```
<table class='TFtable'>
   <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Sort Order</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: records">
       <tr id="mainFactors">
            <td data-bind="if: SortOrderLen === 2"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Description"></td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Should `SortOrder` be an `observableArray` since you want to take the `length` of it? If it should be a string, initialize it to `''`

Answer (score 3):

### Problem 1:

When initializing an `observable` without an argument, its value becomes `undefined`:

```
self.SortOrder = ko.observable();
console.log(self.SortOrder()); // Prints: undefined
```

When trying to access a property of `undefined`, an error is thrown:

```
(undefined).length; // Throws: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

### Fix 1:

Either make sure your computed can handle `undefined` values:

```
self.SortOrderLen = ko.computed(function() {
  if (!self.SortOrder()) return 0;

  return self.SortOrder().length;
});
```

or make sure `SortOrder` is initialized with a valid value:

```
self.SortOrder = ko.observable([]);
```

### Problem 2:

When you want to use a `computed` or other `observable`'s value you need to call it (it's a function).

```
self.SortOrder;    // Returns the `computed` instance
self.SortOrder();  // Returns the actual value inside
```

Therefore, this binding **will not** work:

```
// never `true`, since a ko.computed !== 2
data-bind="if: SortOrderLen === 2"
```

### Fix 2:

Unwrap the value in the binding:

```
data-bind="if: SortOrderLen() === 2"
```

Comment: This answer is much more complete than mine, recommend running through this one first, but still look at the implementation options given in my answer.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed explanation!  Very informative

Comment: I really liked your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the visible binding for this:

```
data-bind="visible: shouldShow"
```

or alternatively you can do the if logic in a comment

```
<!-- ko if: someExpressionGoesHere -->
   <td>show element</td>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: I like using the comment technique for this type of thing but there is a valid argument that this clutters the DOM

Comment: Thank you, could you tell me if I got the expression correct?  <td data-bind="if: SortOrder, precision: 2"> or do I need to handle it another way?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the syntax should be like a normal if statement in javascript eg: data-bind="visible: SortOrder && precision === 2" for me if I'm checking multiple conditions I would push this to a function data-bind="visible: $parent.checkSort(SortOrder, precision)" a do the evaluation in your js. So I haven't seen your example before.

Comment: fyi the $parent is used to access a function in your viewmodel that is not in the loop